# Dell Inspiron 7377 Sound Problem

Tags: 14.04, sound, dell, pulseaudio, alsa

Install of 14.04.1 was smooth, and everything runs beautifully...except there's no sound.
At all.
It shows that I'm using the realtek ALC283 drivers, and the card shows up in both ALSA and pavucontrol, and pavucontrol shows that there's sound being passed to it...so why's it silent?  I've tried all the workarounds that I could find via a google search, but to no avail.
Headphone sound works (I have no idea if HDMI sound works...I don't have a flatscreen I can test it on right now), but that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Do you have dual boot with windows8 ? In this case, you have to switch off computer from windows (not reboot) , else sound card is in strange state (no speaker  ).
- Also test with alsamixer launched in a terminal and tweak the "automute "  switch (normaly must be enabled but...) and speaker volume
  [About alsamixer](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/Alsamixer)